# How to add number vise page changing in angular material 9 mat paginator

Tags: angular9

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDkLq.png)

I want to change my page number vise in using mat-pagination can anyone help me in that

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOUDE.png)

I'm trying to change pages of the table by using page number but it is not working in mat paginator in angular 9